# Why does the new LiveData builder from Kotlin May update not working in my project

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

[image]

Here are my dependencies:

```
 //Room and Lifecycle Libraries
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha02"
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha02'
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-alpha02"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
```

As you can see, I implemented the final versions and yet I do not have access to the liveData builder. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines):

> For `liveData`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01` or higher.

So you're just missing the dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha03"
```

Comment: Thank you, that was all I needed! (y)